# Auto resize Iframe height

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am in a situation where I need my iframe to auto resize it's height. I have done some research and come with some solution to this, but my problem is slightly different.
The iframe has a form in it, on clicking the submit button an output is generated and the height of the content I want to display is changed.
How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event listener on the iframe tags load event and have this trigger your resize code.

Here's a little lib that does this and solves a lot of other issues with keeping an iFrame the correct size.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer**